# Can/Should I share model classes between client and web API?

Tags: c#, rest, inheritance

I'm writing a Blazor WebAssembly client app. that interacts with a web API service.  I'm using DTOs to transfer data between them so I'm good there.  The issue is there are some rather complex classes with lots of properties and lots of methods that need to be shared on both the client and the server.  I don't want to duplicate tons of code.  I was thinking about putting the common parts in an assembly that's used by both client and server, perhaps using inheritance (e.g., PlayerCommon has children PlayerClient and PlayerServer), but I've run into issues with further inheritance (e.g., MachinePlayer is a child of PlayerServer).

Are there best practices about doing this (or not doing it)?  I want to keep it as simple as possible and minimize the amount of duplicate code.  I was thinking of using Partial classes, but I don't think that works across assemblies.

Thanks for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: It's kind of one of the main selling points of having the same language client and server side.

Comment: If it has "lots of methods" is it really a DTO?  From a practical standpoint sharing POCO classes is certainly handy to do.  If there's any chance this is going to be an externally facing service you're probably better of using something like swagger to enable clients to easily build their own poco classes.

Answer (score 2):

Provided your consumer is dotnet app sharing API requests/responses/DTOs is very helpful.

we are using the following setup:

1. ProjectName.ApiModels - .net standard 2.0 project without any dependencies, which just defines classes used in request/response actions. This project references by Project.Web which contains all controllers.
2. ProjectName.Client - .net standard 2.0 project which builds HttpClient and adds operations around methods available.

In this way client and server apps can use different frameworks, e.g. .net core, .net framework.